# The number of Google Search console clicks is lower than Orgainc Search in Google Analytics

Tags: google-apps-script, search, google-analytics, cluster-analysis, google-search-console

Today I found a number of Google Search console clicks is lower than Organic Search in our Google Analytics, which makes me so confused,  let me explain:
on June first, we had 28 organic search users(24 new users), who visited our website with different landing pages.
[this is a screenshot from GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqPL4.png)

But after I checked the search console clicks on the same day, we only had 4
[this is a screenshot from GSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lNyr.png)

Could anyone help me to understand what caused this difference, and which data platform should I trust if I wanna know how many people get into my website through google search results?

Comment: I have the same problem, although in my case it's the other way around. That is...
Google doesn't have Analytics data but Google Search has a considerable increase.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Google Search Console vs. Google Analytics Data Difference](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86032/google-search-console-vs-google-analytics-data-difference)

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, we will need to see the difference between how Google Analytics and search console data. They have very different methods of measuring and attributing a visit.

1. **Google search console** shows the clicks on the total Google search appearances/impressions. Search console's performance metrics are based on what happens on the search results, it's measuring impressions on that, and clicks on your site's listing.
2. **Google Analytics** is showing the organic users(active users in GA4) from **overall Organic**. Analytics measures users on the site, and can attribute visits to how the user last came to the site. So someone could arrive at your site from a Google search, then come directly back later, and analytics would count them as organic users.

For more information-  See the Data Discrepancies towards the bottom of this page.https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7576553?hl=en